# React App + Express JS Server + Axios frontend request = "undefined" options params on Server

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, sequelize.js

I have Googled this problem over and over and can't seem to find the solution.

Here is my frontend code:

```
export const getBlog = (sortColumn, sortOrder) => async dispatch => {
  
 console.log("blogActions.js => getBlog() executed.");
 console.log("sortColumn = " + sortColumn);
 console.log("sortOrder = " + sortOrder);

 let options = {
            order: [sortColumn, sortOrder]
            };
            

  try{
  // call the api. Get all our feedback from our endpoint.
  const res = await axios.get('/api/blog', options

    
  /*
  {
    params: {
      sortColumn: "Heading", 
      sortOrder: "ASC"
        }
    } */
  );
```

Here is my backend code:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('/api/blog - get');
    
    // Return all blog.
    // We need to query our database to get our data.
    // We will do this by using the findAll() function, to get all the feedback in the feedbacks table.
    // Note: Remember if we use await, we need an async before(req, res).

    console.log("req.query = " + req.query);
    console.log("req.params = " + req.params);
    //const { sortColumn, sortOrder} = req.params;
    const { sortColumn, sortOrder} = req.query;
    console.log(sortColumn);
    console.log(sortOrder);


    try{
    const list = await Blog.findAll(
      
      /*
      {
      order: [[sequelize.col(sortColumn)]]
      } 
    */
    );

    // send the list back to the client.
    res.send(list);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e); // error
    }

  });
```

The req.query and req.params on the backend both result in "undefined".

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Kind Regards,

John
Melbourne, Australia

This is the debugging output on the server when requesting data from the frontend client:

[frontend request, VS Code server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd16z.png)

I have tried using Postman and the params get passed through just fine, as you can see here:
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9K7v.png)

[VS Code server console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCeJ5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Axios option for URL query parameters is `params`...

> `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
> Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object

[See Axios - Request Config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

If you expect to receive `sortColumn` and `sortOrder` params in `req.query`, you'll need to construct your options like this

```js
axios.get("/api/blog", { params: { sortColumn, sortOrder } })
```

A word of warning though, some versions of Axios have a bug around URL query serialisation. I would always recommend using the Fetch API instead of Axios.

```js
const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL;
  // or "http://localhost:3001/", etc

const url = new URL("/api/blog", baseURL);
url.searchParams.append("sortColumn", sortColumn);
url.searchParams.append("sortOrder", sortOrder);

const res = await fetch(url);
const data = await res.json();
```

---

If you wanted to use `req.params`, you'd need to define your route with [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters)

```js
router.get("/:sortColumn/:sortOrder", (req, res) => {
  const { sortColumn, sortOrder } = req.params;

  // ...
});
```

and send the request like this

```js
axios.get(
  `/api/blog/${
    encodeURIComponent(sortColumn)
  }/${
    encodeURIComponent(sortOrder)
  }`
)
```

I would **not** recommend this method for this type of request.

Comment: Yes, I did try that already, as you can see in the commented code there, but still the same problem.

Comment: @jm03 how was I to know that? Commented out code does nothing. What do your two client-side logs for `console.log("sortColumn = " + sortColumn)` and `console.log("sortOrder = " + sortOrder)` show? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request and make sure it has a query string

Comment: Yes, sorry, Phil. It's my first time posting on StackOverflow. Thanks for educating me :-)

Comment: @jm03 what version of Axios are you using? Some versions had problems with query parameter serialisation

Comment: I'm using axios 1.4.0

Comment: @jm03 ok, that one should be fine. There's no functional difference between this and the accepted answer. They both add the same query parameters (only this one safely) so if this doesn't work and the other answer does, there's something else going wrong

Answer (score -1):

try change your axios get to this, the req query should be there in req.query

```
axios.get(`/api/blog?sortColumn=${sortColumn}&sortOrder=${sortOrder}`);
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem beautifully. But, I can't understand why my way didn't work when I was following the documentation.     Would you be able to please explain to me why your way worked and my way didn't?

Comment: This is very unsafe. Any value used may break if it is not correctly encoded for URL usage

Comment: How would you do it, Phil?

Comment: @Phil Yes, sorry, I just saw your answer. I'm such a SO n00b. Thanks so much, mate. You're a champ.